# matplotlib graph not appearing in tkinter frame when embedding

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to embed a graph into a tkinter frame. The graph does not appear, but it seems that it takes up space, so the graph is invisible as I am also not getting any errors.

I inititally tried embedding some stock market data, but even trying to embed a simple line graph, it won't work, so this eliminated my suspects of the graph just erroring out.
When I do plt.show(), the graph appears in its own window, which is not what I want, as I want it embedded in a tkinter frame.

In the image below you can see the area where the graph thinks it is. The graph and the hello label are in the same frame, so the frame is still displaying fine.

[image]

My code for this looks as follows:

```
def matplot(self,parent):
        new_frame = Frame(self.detailed_frame,width=150,height=150)
        new_frame.pack()

        test_label = Label(new_frame,text='hello',font='Arial 16 bold')
        test_label.pack()

        plt.plot([120, 2, 3, 4], [120, 4, 9, 16], '-o')
        #plt.show()


        fig = Figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = new_frame)
        canvas.draw()
        get_widz = canvas.get_tk_widget()
        get_widz.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.detailed_frame)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

 def info_page(self,parent):
        # important variables
        self.months = [...]
        self.days = [...]
        self.days_31= [...]

        self.years = self.year_data

        # main code

        self.detailed_frame = Frame(root)
        self.detailed_frame.grid(column=2,row=0)
        root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.matplot(root)

        # label of investment
        label1 = Label(self.detailed_frame,text='Selected Investment',font='Arial 16 bold',padx=125)
        label1.pack()

        # name of investment
        but1 = Label(self.detailed_frame,textvariable=self.saved_comp)
        but1.pack()

        # string vars for option box
        self.month_var = StringVar()
        self.month_var.set(self.months[0])

        self.day_var = StringVar()
        self.day_var.set(self.days[0])

        self.year_var = StringVar()
        self.year_var.set(self.years[0])

        # list box frame CURSED!
        listbox_frame = Frame(self.detailed_frame)
        listbox_frame.pack()

        # listbox date selector

        month_dropdown = OptionMenu(listbox_frame, self.month_var, *self.months)
        month_dropdown.grid(column=0,row=0)

        day_dropdown = OptionMenu(listbox_frame, self.day_var, *self.days)
        day_dropdown.grid(column=1,row=0)

        year_dropdown = OptionMenu(listbox_frame, self.year_var, *self.years)
        year_dropdown.grid(column=2,row=0)

        self.month_var.trace("w",self.callback)
        self.day_var.trace("w", self.callback)
        self.year_var.trace("w",self.callback)

        # more generic widgets
        self.scale_value = Label(self.detailed_frame, text="0")
        self.scale_value.pack()

        # slider thing
        self.vertical = ttk.Scale(self.detailed_frame,from_=0,to=100,orient=HORIZONTAL,value=0,command=self.slide,length=200)
        self.vertical.pack()

        self.enter_amount = Entry(self.detailed_frame)
        self.enter_amount.pack()

        calculate_amount = Button(self.detailed_frame,text='save',command = lambda:self.calc_amt())
        calculate_amount.pack()
```

Comment: You made a plt and you made a fig, but at no point did you link the 2 together.

Comment: ah thanks i got it using:
fig.add_subplot(111).plot([120, 2, 3, 4], [120, 4, 9, 16], '-o') however, i dont understand what the add_subplot(111) does, could you elaborate?

Comment: You need to use the show() command to actually display the graph. I think that might be the problem.